# iText 5.5.3 PdfPTable.keepRowsTogether() isn't working as expected when setSkipFirstHeader(true) is set

Tags: java, itext

I am getting an interesting scenario in iText where a table at the bottom of a columnText is splitting up rows unexpectedly.  I have written some code to simulate the situation I am seeing and the result produced is shown in the image below:

[image]

The image above can be reproduced with the following code:

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(400, 220));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File("test.pdf")));

document.open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.setHeaderRows(2);
table.setSplitLate(false);
table.setSplitRows(true);
table.setSkipFirstHeader(true);

table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);

table.addCell("Header (Continued)");
table.addCell("Subheader (Continued)");

table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);

table.addCell("Header");
table.addCell("Subheader");
table.addCell("Row 1");
table.addCell("Row 2");
table.addCell("Row 3");
table.addCell("Row 4");

ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
columnText.addElement(table);

columnText.setSimpleColumn(36, 158, 364, 184);
columnText.go();

columnText.setSimpleColumn(36, 36, 364, 148);
columnText.go();

document.close();
```

Notice that the actual lines marked as header have been highlighted gray.  I have tried using `table.keepRowsTogether(new int[] { 1 });`, `table.keepRowsTogether(new int[] { 3 });` and even `table.keepRowsTogether(0);` but the splitting still happens.  I was originally confusing myself by thinking that the rows with `Header` and `Subheader` were also part of the header rows but in fact they are simply rows to simulate a separate header text on the first page.  Any ideas how to keep the second non-header row with the first non-header row?

Comment: After thinking about it I actually would want `table.keepRowsTogether(new int[] { 1, 2 });` to keep the fake header and subheader together as well as `Row 1` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug.  I worked with the iText support team on this and they were able to come up with a solution.  The fix appears to have made it into the 5.5.6 release.